# github actions, split gradle calls accross jobs

Tags: android, gradle, github-actions

In my github actions jobs I would like to have n jobs.

- job 1 would run `gradle assembleDebug`
- job 2 to job n would run `gradle connectedCheck`. The difference between each job is the image used on the android emulator (each with a different android api)

The idea is that the project is built in job1 while job2 to job n would reuse what was already built in job1 and only build the tests (that are made by a task run by connectedCheck). This is in order to avoid having everything built from scratch in job2 to job n.

I already:

- save the `app/build` `app/.cxx` files into a github cache in job1
- restore that cache in job2 to job n.

I tried to `touch` the files in `app/build` & `app/.cxx` before running gradle again (so that I'm sure the files are all older than the source files).

But this still doesn't permit to gain in build time. In other words, the system still rebuilds everything, gradle runs the tasks that were done in job1 again.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found that:

- `touch` was useless
- the source files must have the same timestamps across the jobs. If github gets the repo with a git checkout, the files will have the timestamp of the time of the checkout. So to have always the same timestamp, you may use [git-restore-mtime](https://github.com/MestreLion/git-tools/blob/main/git-restore-mtime). There is a github actions [chetan/git-restore-mtime-action@v1](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/git-restore-mtime) for it.
- I also had to add the `$PROJECT_DIR/.gradle` directory.

In addition to that, by running:

- `gradle` with `-i` option
- `ninja` with `-d explain -v` options

I found that:

- I had other `build/` dirs in other places than just in `app/build/`. Typically in some of the libraries I use. For example in `additional_lib/my_lib/build/`
- this file is also needed: `~/.android/debug.keystore`
- the files & dirs in `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/ndk/<version>` and `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmake/<version>` must have the same timestamp across the jobs.

So in the job you have to:

1. be sure that the source files have the same timestamp across the jobs

   - set fetch-depth to 0

     ```yaml
       - name: checkout
         uses: actions/checkout@v3
         with:
           fetch-depth: 0
     ```
   - use [chetan/git-restore-mtime-action@v1](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/git-restore-mtime)

     ```yaml
       - name: restore timestamps
         uses: chetan/git-restore-mtime-action@v1
     ```
2. be sure that files in these dirs have the same timestamp across the jobs.

   - ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/ndk/
   - ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmake/
3. cache these folders:

   - .gradle/
   - app/build/
   - app/.cxx/
   - additional_lib/my_lib/build/
   - ~/.gradle/
   - ~/.android/debug.keystore

Note: I also added ~/.gradle in the cache, but this is probably not mandatory